# Multiple sliders with two number inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, nouislider

I'm trying to make [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) work with one class on multiple locations in the same page. Right now i have 2 sliders, both are working fine, except for a strange behavior when i change the value of the second input, it actually updates the first handle and input. I'll be gratefull if someone helps me.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z83oz9np/265/)

```js
function bindValues(price_slider, inputNumberMin, inputNumberMax){
       price_slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
        var value = values[handle];

        if ( handle ) {
            inputNumberMax.value = Math.round(value);
        } else {
            inputNumberMin.value = Math.round(value);
        }
      });
      inputNumberMin.addEventListener('change', function(){
          price_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
      });
      inputNumberMax.addEventListener('change', function(){
          price_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);     
      });

  }
  var price_sliders = $('.price-filter');
  var inputsNumberMin = $('.price-filter-min-price');
  var inputsNumberMax = $('.price-filter-max-price');
  for ( var i = 0; i < price_sliders.length; i++ ) {
      noUiSlider.create(price_sliders[i], {
          start: [0, 100],
          connect: true,
          range: {
              'min': 0,
              'max': 100
          }
      });
      bindValues(price_sliders[i], inputsNumberMin[i], inputsNumberMax[i]);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.1.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="price-filter"></div>
<input type="number" class="price-filter-min-price">
<input type="number" class="price-filter-max-price">
<div class="price-filter"></div>
<input type="number" class="price-filter-min-price">
<input type="number" class="price-filter-max-price">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this:

```
  inputNumberMin.addEventListener('change', function(){
      price_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
  });
  inputNumberMax.addEventListener('change', function(){
      price_slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value); // <<< here   
  });
```

The `set` method takes an array of values for the whole slider. If a single value is passed, that is set on the first handle. Instead, you'll have to be explicit about which value you want to update:

```
price_slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]); // 'null' values are ignored.
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/z83oz9np/268/